# Issue parsing dates on devices running iOS and MacOS (apple) operating systems

Tags: javascript, ios, datetime, date-format

I have a web application that deals with different time zones. This app stores all the dates in `UTC + 00:00` and converts the time to local time right before displaying it using a set of functions I wrote.

It all works well from converting the `date string` to a `datetime object`, converting the `datetime object` from `UTC +00:00` to local time, but after I obtain the local `datetime string`
using `date.toLocaleString()`, I cannot format it as I want because it returns the following format: `3/23/2021, 9:19:00 PM`, and literally all apple devices I tried cannot parse this string and convert it to a valid date.

I simply want to get the local time and format it from `3/23/2021, 9:19:00 PM` to `23 Mar 2021 21:19`. I have written a function that does this formatting for me but the browser cannot parse `3/23/2021, 9:19:00 PM` from a string and convert it to a `date object`.

I am developing the application in React JS (JavaScript).

Here is the function that does the string parsing and date formatting:

```
const formatDateString = date => {
    const parsed = new Date(Date.parse(date.replace(",", "")))

    const months_string = "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec"
    const months_array = months_string.split(" ")

    let output = ""

    output = output + parsed.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + parsed.getDate() : parsed.getDate()
    output = output + " " + months_array[parsed.getMonth()]
    output = output + " " + parsed.getFullYear()
    let hours = parsed.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + parsed.getHours() : parsed.getHours()
    output = output + " " + hours
    let minutes = parsed.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + parsed.getMinutes() : parsed.getMinutes()
    output = output + ":" + minutes


    return output
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are converting a Date to a string / then back to a Date / then using the components (`.getMonth()` `.getFullYear()` etc), instead of just getting those values from the original Date object directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up avoiding the parsing problem altogether and creating my own parser that will work for **MY** scenario. This solution only applies if your input format is same as mine, although it can be modified to work with virtually any date format. Here is the code:

```
export const formatDateStringApple = date_string => {

    const months_string = "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec"
    const months_array = months_string.split(" ")
    
    const split_datetime = date_string.split(" ")
    const date = split_datetime[0].replace(",", "")
    const _split_time = split_datetime[1].split(" ")
    const time = _split_time[0]
    const isPm = _split_time[1] == "PM" ? true : false

    const split_date = date.split("/")
    const split_time = time.split(":")

    return `${split_date[1]} ${months_array[split_date[0] - 1]} ${split_date[2]} ${isPm ? split_time[0] + 12 : split_time[0] < 10 ? "0" + split_time[0] : split_time[0]}:${split_time[1]}`
}
```

Maybe (probably) there is a better way of doing this, but this is the quickest one I could come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Your question states that your code *"works well from converting the `date string` to a `datetime object` ..."*

Would this work for you?

```
let d = new Date();

var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
var s = d.toLocaleString('en-GB', options);

options = { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' };
s += ' ' + d.toLocaleString('en-GB', options);

console.log(s);

// output:
// 24 Mar 2021 10:26
```

Note: using 'en-GB' puts the date in "Day Month Year" order.